# How to redirect from http to https in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, https

my website is using https protocol. When I do a action like submit a form, it redirect to http, not to https.
I used this way.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
   TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
         SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
         securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
         SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
         collection.addPattern("/*");
         securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
         context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
      }
   };
   tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
   return tomcat;
}


private Connector createHttpConnector() {
   Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
   connector.setScheme("http");
   connector.setPort(8080);
   connector.setSecure(false);
   connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
   return connector;
}
```

But It show error when building "Address already in use: bind".
Could you hep me resolve this problem?

Comment: Please share your stacktrace so I can help.

Comment: Also share you ```application.properties``` configurations.this can help

Comment: @Sophie-Nguyen Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you have to kill process for that particular port

**In windows**

```
netstat -ano
```

will list all the protocols, ports and processes listening . Use

```
taskkill -pid "proces to kill" /f
```

to kill the process listening to the port. e.g

```
 taskkill -pid 431 /f
```

**In Linux**

If you know what port the process is running you can type:  `lsof -i:<port>`.

For instance,    `lsof -i:8080` , to list the process (pid) running on port 8080.

Then kill the process with `kill <pid>` .

**If after running above step it does not work than verify your step**

**For Enabling HTTPS in Spring Boot follow these three step.**

Step 1.Get yourself a SSL certificate: generate a self-signed certifcate or get one from a Certificate Authority

Step 2.Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot.

- add below configuration in application.properties file at location
  src/main/resources

  ```
  server.port: 8443
  server.ssl.key-store: <keystore> (e.g.keystore.p12) 
  server.ssl.key-store-password: <key-store-password> (e.g.mypassword)
  server.ssl.keyStoreType: <keyStoreType>(e.g.PKCS12)
  server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
  ```

Step 3.Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Which you already completed)

For more details refer [Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/)